# GitPython and sending commands to the Git object

Tags: python, git

[GitPython](http://gitorious.org/git-python) is a way of interacting with git from python. I'm trying to access the basic git commands (e.g. `git commit -m "message"`) from this module, which according to [this](http://pysync.googlecode.com/files/GitPython.pdf) should be accessed through the Git module. Here's what I've tried so far to get these commands working:

```
>>> import git
>>> foo = git.Git("~/git/GitPython")
>>> bar = "git commit -m 'message'"
>>> beef = git.Git.execute(foo,bar)
```

This shows up an error saying that there is no such file or directory. I've also tried the following as paths to my git directory:

`~/git/GitPython/.git`
`/Users/bacon/git/gitclient/`

The only other option is that the command is wrong, so I tried:
`commit -m "message"` as well, and still get "no such file or directory".

What do I need to do to get these git commands working properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I havn't tried it to verify yet but it seems git.Git.execute expects a list of commandline arguments (if you give it a string it'll look for an executable exactly matching the string, spaces and everything - which naturally wouldn't be found), so something like this I think would work:

```
import git
import os, os.path
g = git.Git(os.path.expanduser("~/git/GitPython"))
result = g.execute(["git", "commit", "-m", "'message'"])
```

other changes:

- I expect using a path with ~ in it wouldn't work so I used os.path.expanduser to expand ~ to your home directory
- using instance.method(*args) instead of Class.method(instance, *args) is generally preferred so I changed that, though it'd still work with the other way

There might be saner ways than manually running the commit command though (I just didn't notice any quickly looking through the source) so I suggest making sure there isn't a higher-level way before doing it that way

Comment: Having tried this, I get a console message: "git.errors.GitCommandError: '[\'git'\,...] returned exit status 129". Thanks for passing the arguments as a list though, very helpful :)

Comment: Eventually got it working using ['git''commit', '-a', '-m "message"'] using this method. Many thanks again, you rock

Comment: Why isn't the documentation more clear?  Or the 'tutorial' actually more of a tutorial?  Python docs can be frustrating sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial it says ...

```
The first step is to create a ``Repo`` object to represent your repository.

    >>> from git import *
    >>> repo = Repo("/Users/mtrier/Development/git-python")
```

I don't see your Repo.

I am looking at the file named tutorial.rst in the doc directory of GitPython.

Answer (score 0):

In general, ~ expansion is done by your shell and is not a feature of the file system, so you shouldn't expect it to work.

os.path.expanduser can apply the expansion for you, but in general you're better off writing out the full path (since then the script works whoever runs it, providing they have access to your files).

I suspect you want:

```
'/Users/bacon/git/GitPython'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution was tested with `gitPython 3.1.26`

```
import git
foo = git.Git("~/git/GitPython")
cmd1 = "git add -A"
bar = "git commit -m 'message'"
foo.execute(f"{cmd1}; {bar}", shell=True, istream=PIPE, with_stdout=True)
```

As it can be seing `gitPython` just not only can execute commands in string form, but also can execute more than one command in a single call.

[This post about executing multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649355/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-one-process-using-popen) gave me the idea. `Popen` is the base of `git.Git.execute`.

Unfortunately I searched the official `gitPython` documentation and other sites and couldn't find a similar example using `git.Git.execute`.