# Converting a bash script into Python using subprocess module

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, sh, popen

I am trying to convert a bash script into a subprocess so I can schedule different parameters. Here is my original bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -xe

export NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
export TF_CUDNN_RESET_RND_GEN_STATE=1

python3 -u DeepSpeech.py \
  --train_files /external_data/data_csvs/train.csv \
  --test_files  /external_data/data_csvs/test.csv \
  --dev_files  /external_data/data_csvs/dev.csv \
  --epochs 30 \
  --train_batch_size 32 \
  --dev_batch_size 32 \
  --test_batch_size 32 \
  --export_dir /external_data/deepspeech_models/ \
  --use_allow_growth  \
  --n_hidden 2048 \
  --train_cudnn  \
  --learning_rate 0.00005 \
  --dropout_rate 0.40 \
  --summary_dir /external_data/tensorboard_summaries/ \
  --checkpoint_dir /external_data/mozilla_release_chkpts/deepspeech-0.7.4-checkpoint/ | tee //tmp/external/deepspeech_models/progress.txt \
  "$@"
```

Now I am trying to convert this into a subprocess with the following:

```
    subprocess.Popen([
        'set', '-xe',
        'export', 'NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0',
        'export', 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0',
        'export', 'TF_CUDNN_RESET_RND_GEN_STATE=1',
        'python3', '-u', 'DeepSpeech.py',
        '--train_files', '/external_data/data_csvs/train.csv',
        '--test_files'  '/external_data/data_csvs/test.csv',
        '--dev_files', '/external_data/data_csvs/dev.csv',
        '--epochs', str(epochs),
        '--train_batch_size', str(trainbs),
        '--dev_batch_size', str(devbs),
        '--test_batch_size', str(testbs),
        '--export_dir', '/external_data/deepspeech_models/',
        '--use_allow_growth',  
        '--n_hidden', str(2048),
        '--train_cudnn',  
        '--learning_rate', str(lr),
        '--summary_dir', '/external_data/tensorboard_summaries/' 
        '--checkpoint_dir', '/external_data/mozilla_release_chkpts/deepspeech-0.7.4-checkpoint/', '|', 'tee', '/external_data/deepspeech_models/Deepspeech_progress.txt',
        '$@'], shell = True, cwd = '//DeepSpeech/', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, executable = '/bin/sh')
```

the str() values are just values I am using as variables into my subprocess.

It runs without error but nothing happens. Am I missing something? The bash script config runs fine. Also, how would I go about getting output processed to stdout when I run the script?

Comment: What output are you expecting? Can you see the process in `top`?

Comment: @Dallan I am training a neural network using tensorflow. I should be seeing some model progress and some steps being taken. The process is not in ```top``` Perhaps I need to add the '\' into my subprocess ?

Comment: You are missing the `;` between the individual commands. Right now, everything is being passed as arguments to `set`

Comment: @Dallan Of course! Ok. would those go as separate ';' tokens in my list of arguments?

Comment: Since it's a python script, could it be important as module and function in it called instead of trying through shell from python as another python process? If you must like this, you can use `subprocess.run()`

Comment: There are multiple things going on. First. If its a python script, could you import it as a module instead and call a function in it instead of calling Python from Python through shell. Next, `subprocess.Popen` forks a child and starts a new process, but does not wait for it to finish, you should look at `subprocess.run` or you might want to `wait` for the child to finish. You do not need shell to get involved and can/should set environment variables of child with `env` dict instead of those `export` lines and `set -xe` is not really meaningful in this context.

Comment: @OndrejK. I will take a look into ```subprocess.run```. Care to expand a bit on the ```export``` vs ```env``` comment? I will take a look at them in google soon as well.

Comment: Instead of `"export VAR1=val1; export VAR2=val2; command arg1 arg2", shell=True`, you say: `["command", "arg1", "arg2"], env={"VAR1": "val1", "VAR2": "val2"}` and you can happily leave shell out of it with default `False`. Besides even in shell itself, when you write a one-liner, you can export variables for a single command by prepending them to its command line. I.e. `VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2 command arg1 arg2` instead `export` which has to be separate command terminated by newline or `;`.

Comment: @OndrejK. Awesome. Thank you for this. Today is my first real use of ```subprocess``` so all of these pointers really help. The main reason I am calling a python script this way is because I am running a Tensorflow model with DeepSpeech which is a large project. I am adding a capability to schedule models with varying hyperparameters that 
come from a CSV schedule and using ```subprocess``` seems to be the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10596335/5075269), you need to separate the individual commands with `;`.

In your case, try something like:

```
train_cmd = ['python3', '-u', 'DeepSpeech.py',
            '--train_files', '/external_data/data_csvs/train.csv',
            '--test_files'  '/external_data/data_csvs/test.csv',
            '--dev_files', '/external_data/data_csvs/dev.csv',
            '--epochs', str(epochs),
            '--train_batch_size', str(trainbs),
            '--dev_batch_size', str(devbs),
            '--test_batch_size', str(testbs),
            '--export_dir', '/external_data/deepspeech_models/',
            '--use_allow_growth',  
            '--n_hidden', str(2048),
            '--train_cudnn',  
            '--learning_rate', str(lr),
            '--summary_dir', '/external_data/tensorboard_summaries/' 
            '--checkpoint_dir', '/external_data/mozilla_release_chkpts/deepspeech-0.7.4-checkpoint/', '|', 'tee', '/external_data/deepspeech_models/Deepspeech_progress.txt',
            '$@']
cmds = ['set -xe', 
        'export NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0', 
        'export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0',
        'export TF_CUDNN_RESET_RND_GEN_STATE=1',
        ' '.join(train_cmd)]
subprocess.Popen('; '.join(cmds), shell = True, cwd = '//DeepSpeech/', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, executable = '/bin/sh')
```

Comment: How come in my original bash script, I didn't need the semicolons? Pretty new to bash scripting so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Coldchain9 The bash script simply puts each command into the shell sequentially, splitting on newlines (the \ escapes the newlines in your python command). If you wanted to run it in the shell with one command, you would also have to join them with semicolons. See: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch28_16.htm

Comment: This is all incredibly helpful. It is now starting and completes some of the starting process but then I get a ```BrokenPipeError```

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it by removing the stdout argument. IT is now running and working. Thank you a ton for your help. I will accept as the answer soon.